# Why am i not receiving bonus points for associating stackoverflow sites?

Tags: support

I have joined in several stackoverflow sites but I am not receiving any association points automatically. I am not sure how to declare this points. Help me out please.

Comment: That's not a question related to that part of resource :)

Comment: this is off topic for SO but you must be trusted on one site to receive an association bonus. For example, I earned 200 reputation points here then I got the bonus. When I joined other sites i got the bonus there too.

Comment: 1. Questions regarding the site itself belong on Meta, not here. 2. You need to have a lot of rep on another site first. I believe for Stack Overflow, once you have 1000 rep, you're considered trusted. I don't know if it's the same for all sites, but you'll definitely need more than the 6 rep that you have on Tex.

Comment: According to [Stack Overflow Blog - Cross-Site Account Associations](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/), you need at least 200 reputation on one site to get the association bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You require a minimum of 200 reputation *somewhere* on the network.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/)  If you have less, you will not receive the association bonus for creating new accounts on the network.

Remember, this is a measure of trust on the network.  Having 200 reputation is the barrier to cross when measuring that trust.  If you have less than that, you're not trusted on the network enough to justify letting you pass the basic limitations.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. But some other people said the same thing but on the comment. So how does this work? If I have a question about something, clearly I don't understand it properly. Why am I getting negative points?

Comment: @ImtiazAhmed Because it doesn't appear as if you had searched the site prior to posting this question; you can see it was marked as a duplicate of another question that was asked earlier.